# How to recover after deleting Ubuntu partition?

Tags: grub2, windows-7, nomodeset

I have a really old Compaq presario, I recently just wiped it clean and started again. I put Windows 7 on but, half way through installing it ran out of battery... Thinking nothing of it I just done it again, I partitioned my harddrive installed Ununtu 12.04.4.

No all went well, it ran fine it ran better than before infact, Ubuntu ran smoothly and I had no troubles (apart from getting used to it)  so anyway. Today I was looking in disc management and noticed my hard drive was in 4 parts... Long story short I deleted Ubuntu partiton and on reboot it went to the grub recovery etc etc.

I didn't want to bother anyone on here with n00b like question, but. I tried everything on askubuntu I tried the ls (hd0,msdos1/2/3) etc I tried to fix the graphics thingy in the purple screen? Everytjing.

I tried to reboot windows to repair partition or whatever, but when I load it up it either has a black screen with a flashing  ' - '  or it will say

'Press any key to boot from DVD' etc I push a key and then it just goes black and my disc drive makes sounds as though it's working?

Is this a problem I can fix ? Or is my computer ruined?

Sorry for bad spelling grammar I'm doing this on my phone quickly.

Okay, here is a more detailed( I hope anyway) version of the above taking into account everything I have been told just a minuet ago.

Okay, I'll try and break it down as easy as possible. So, set up computer > it ran fine > today I deleted the partition that had Ubuntu on it. I restarted my computer and was confronted with Grub rescue> I looked up how I could recover partition I.e the ls (hd0,msdos1 or 2 etc and everytime on every code it came back with 'unknown filesystem'

so from here I looked what else it might be. Someone suggested I run windows through disc and repair windows. Which leads me to the black screen with a flashing  ' - ' OR if it asks me to press any key to boot from CD or DVD, I would press enter and my disc drive would make the noises it normally does when working, but the screen would just be black.

SO I tried to go into BIOS fix some settings in there, save&exit > comp restarts > exactly the same things happen.

now if I have the Ubuntu disc in, SOMETIMES it will have the grub rescue screen and sometimes it will come up with the purple screen and the two icons at the bottom of the screen, now, if I press a key SOMETIMES it will go to a still screen with UBUNTU(not the loading one it's just the logo) on it and nothing will happen, other times it won't do anything?

I just tried to have a look at one of the answers about Nomodeset as that sounds like what's up? But every code I punched in(even the one that's potentially dangerous for fan etc) it will just start a new line like I didn't out any code in at all? I really hope that's a bit clearer. Forgot to mention as well that once or twice it has gone to the Ubuntu load up screen as if it's starting up normally? But it won't go any further than that? I really hope that's a bit clearer. Thank you for you time hope I haven't made you all rip your hair out.

Comment: Have you tried nomodeset?

Comment: Is your question that you deleted a partition and want it back? I am not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Hi, yes I deleted the partition, but when the grub screen comes up I tried all the things to fix it that have been posted before, when I have Ubuntu in the grub screen comes up sometimes if I go into BIOS I can make the purple screen appear but either nothing happens when I push the down key to fix graphic thingy (I told you I was a noob) sometimes nothing happens but when I put windows disc in to fix partition problems nothing happens? At all..

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please take your time to write your questions. Choose an appropriate title and tags that show the topic of your question. Unclear questions with unrelated title and tags are less likely to get answers.

Comment: I'm so sorry I hate typing long things on my phone, I must be ruined everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start on a live-dvd and install `testdisk`. The recovery of a deleted partition can be easy if you haven't done any modifications to your HDD since the error.

With that tool, you should be able to recover your disk as it was. It worths at least a try.

Comment: Yes thank you very much! I looked into testdisk but being the only computer I have is now "broken" I will have to get it from a friend. I was just wondering if there is any other way. Ir seem to me that my disc drive has eventually worn out and I believe it's time to upgrade.

Comment: you can do the recovery on a 9.04 disk if you wish, that's not important. All you have to do is access your HDD with testdisk, and let it modify it.

Comment: My friend brought over some brains and testdisk all is well. So sorry for the utter shambles I posted earlier in...

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is fine. I can't give you the details with the information you have provided but it looks like you simply deleted the [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) that held your Ubuntu install. The simplest thing to do would be to reinstall Ubuntu.

If you have indeed deleted the partition that held Ubuntu, reinstalling is the *only* thing you can do apart from restoring from backups and that wouldn't be very easy either. Your Windows install should not have been affected and you should be able to recover everything once you reinstall.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm trying to boot from windows disc but it just shows up with a black screen and a flashing - after I push a key. I've tried to nomodeset and nothing happens it just keeps saying grub rescue>

Comment: @user254018 please [edit] your question to explain that. As it stands we really have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user254018 umm, thanks for accepting but did I actually solve your problem? Please only accept answers that actually answer your question.

Comment: Ohh man, I'm really sorry guys. Maybe if an admin just deletes this thread as it's hard to use my phone to fix this issue and I'm just making people mad!! Thanks for trying to help guys, but I'm not smart enough in computer terms to detail what's wrong properly :/

Comment: @user254018 relax! Just take the time to write your posts carefully and clearly, that's all we ask. Ignorance is not a crime but we do treat laziness as one :)

Comment: Don't worry about it @user254018 - just edit your question into a concise but detailed form and you should get an answer forthwith. Good luck!

Comment: Okay, edited the original post, I hope it's clearer.